# Can not upload the large video by using youtube api v2

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

When i try to upload the large video (500Mb) to youtube using api v2.After config in php.ini like that :

```
session.gc_maxlifetime 10800  
max_input_time         10800
max_execution_time     10800  
upload_max_filesize    600M 
post_max_size          600M
```

I get the error time out :

```
Operation timed out after 100000 milliseconds with 0  bytes received
```

> I resolved my problems,thank for your suppports.You can edit 'request_timeout_seconds' in Google config : \google-api-php-client\src\Google\Config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problems, thank for your suppports.

You can edit 'request_timeout_seconds' in Google config :

> \google-api-php-client\src\Google\Config.php

Answer (score 1):

Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our deprecation policy for more information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_deprecated